# Codeforces. Задача о размене монет. Жадный алгоритм

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Решаю задачу на Codeforces. Не понимаю, почему программа не проходит 12-й тест. Это обычный жадный алгоритм. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка.

Вот условие:

В государстве `R` есть `n + 1` видов монет, самая дешевая из которых имеет номинал `1`, а каждая следующая имеет номинал в `a_i` раз больше предыдущей. Требуется выплатить сумму `s` наименьшим числом монет. Разумеется, можно использовать несколько монет одного номинала.

**Входные данные**

В первой строке записаны два целых числа через пробел: `n` и `s` (`1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5`, `0 ≤ s ≤ 10^9`) - количество типов монет, если не считать самую дешевую, и сумма, которую требуется выплатить.

Во второй строке записаны `n` целых чисел через пробел: `a_i` (`2 ≤ a_i ≤ 10^9`) — количество раз, в которое номинал очередной монеты больше номинала предыдущей.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите единственное целое число — минимальное количество монет, необходимое, чтобы выплатить сумму `s`.

*Может дело во второй строке? А я ставлю ограничение своим `coinNumber`, когда его вводим. Вроде как именно он определяет количество чисел для второй строки.*

входные данные

```
3 42
3 2 2
```

выходные данные

```
4
```

входные данные

```
5 228
5 2 5 2 5
```

выходные данные

```
8
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long coinNumber; long long sumToPay;
    cin >> coinNumber >> sumToPay;
    vector <long long> money{}; money.resize(coinNumber + 1);
    money[0] = 1;

    for (long long i(1); i <= coinNumber; ++i) // The first element is already filled
    {
        cin >> money[i];
        money[i] *= money[i - 1];
    }

    long long needCoin(0);
    for (long long i(coinNumber); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        needCoin += sumToPay / money[i];
        sumToPay %= money[i];
    }

    cout << needCoin;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А URL дать не хотите?

Comment: Возможно переполнение в строке где вы накапливаете номиналы. Останавливайтесь как только превзошли искомую сумму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в переполнении. Рассмотрим такие входные данные:

> ```
> 7 1
> 3 5 17 257 641 65537 6700417
> ```

Ответ должен быть единица. Ваша программа выдаёт `-1` потому что произведение номиналов равно `2^64 - 1`. В массиве `money` последнее значение равно `-1` типа `long long` на 64-битном компьютере.

Исправить ошибку можно изменив порядок размена на обратный. Ваша программа подбирает наибольший номинал, а можно начать с младших. Например:

> ```
> 5 228
> 5 2 5 2 5
> ```

Сколько монет младшего номинала (копеек) нужно что составить сумму `228`? Любая сумма без копеек кратна пяти. Тогда копеек нужно будет `228 % 5`. Когда копейки учтены, сумму можно поделить на пять и перейти к следующему номиналу:

> ```
> sum  factor      coins      next sum
>
> 228    5     228 % 5 = 3  228 / 5 = 45
>  45    2      45 % 2 = 1   45 / 2 = 22
>  22    5      22 % 5 = 2   22 / 5 =  4
>   4    2       4 % 2 = 0    4 / 2 =  2
>   2    5       2 % 5 = 2    2 / 5 =  0
> ```

Процесс аналогичен переводу числа в систему счисления с переменным основанием. Например, если все множители равны десяти, то вычислится сумма цифр в десятичной записи числа. Особенность нашего случая в том что шкала номиналов может кончится до того как сумма обнулится. В этом случае оставшуюся сумму надо прибавить к общему числу монет.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n_nominals;
    int sum;
    std::cin >> n_nominals >> sum;

    int n_coins = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_nominals; ++i) {
        int factor;
        std::cin >> factor;
        n_coins += sum % factor;
        sum /= factor;
    }
    n_coins += sum;

    std::cout << n_coins;
}
```